# Retrieve a count of all duplicated values from one column grouping by unique values in the other column

Tags: sql-server

I have a big table with the two columns:

`Bld_id` - which has multiple unique appartments, so `Bld_id` may repeat multiple times depending on the number of appartments in it.

Second column is `Appartment_Status` which has four possible values:

- ACTIVE,
- NOT ACTIVE
- NULL
- (blank).

So I want to have my output to look like a table of 6 columns

```
Bld_id (unique) 
Count(ACTIVE Status)
Count(NOT ACTIVE Status)
COUNT (NULL Status)
Count (blank Satus)
Count (Total statuses)
```

Grouped by all unique `Bld_id`.

It would be also beneficial to display results of the two statuses below in just one column with the name of Count(No Status)

```
Count (NULL Status)
Count (blank Satus)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this for fun

```
with
--
-- Test case supplied
--
test(Building, Appartement, Status) as
(
  select 1, 1, 'ACTIVE' from dual union all
  select 1, 2, 'ACTIVE' from dual union all
  select 1, 3, 'NOT ACTIVE' from dual union all
  select 1, 4, 'BLANK' from dual union all
  select 1, 5, NULL from dual union all
  select 2, 1, 'ACTIVE' from dual union all
  select 2, 2, 'BLANK' from dual union all
  select 2, 3, 'NOT ACTIVE' from dual union all
  select 2, 4, 'BLANK' from dual union all
  select 2, 5, NULL from dual
)
--
-- SELECT statement
--
select Building,
       sum(case when Status = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) active,
       sum(case when Status = 'NOT ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) NOT_active,
       sum(case when Status = 'BLANK' then 1 else 0 end) Blanks,
       sum(case when Status is null then 1 else 0 end) IS_NULLS,
       sum(case when Status is null or status = 'BLANK' then 1 else 0 end) no_status
  from test
 group by building;
```

Result :

```
  BUILDING     ACTIVE NOT_ACTIVE     BLANKS   IS_NULLS  NO_STATUS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     1      2          1      1      1      2
     2      1          1      2      1      3
```

Is that what you were looking for ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it soon. Pretty much,and one more thing is that I want to treat blanks and nulls as one thing in one combined them column

Comment: Adjust the query as you wish but all the logic is there to do what you want. Have fun.